# Get list returned from ANTLR Parser rule with += syntax

Tags: java, antlr3

I have parser rule

```
s+=statement
```

and my statement rule declaration is as

```
statement returns [List<CommonTree> myList]
```

what Antlr3 generates against this is as:

```
state._fsp--;
if (state.failed) return retval;
if ( state.backtracking==0 ) stream_plsql_statement.add(s.getTree());
if (list_s==null) list_s=new ArrayList();
list_s.add(s.getTree());
```

That means s+=... transforms into the list_s thing.
The problem is that I need to access the list returned from the underlying rule. I have tried

```
$s.myList
```

but it gives an error and code isn't compiled.

Can anyone guide me about how to access this list.